# Newtonsoft.Json Serializer strange behaviour with dynamic and decimals

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, json.net

I'm trying to cast dynamic structure which contains a decimal to a concrete class. I haven't been able to find a reasonable solution to that so I'm using "hacky" way by serializing the dynamic structure to JSON and then by deserializing it back to a concrete class. My first question is - Is there a better way to do that?

Actually I've noticed something really strange for me. After doing what I just explained I was trying to get string values out of those decimal values - `a.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
To my surprise those strings were different! One was `10` and another `10.0`. Can you explain why this happens? During debugging the valus both seem to be the same...

This is my code so you can easily check this:

```
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SimpleFx.UnitTests.UnitTest
{
    public class DecimalStruct
    {
        public DecimalStruct(decimal a)
        {
            A = a;
        }

        public decimal A { get; set; }
    }

    public class DynamicDecimalTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// "Hacky" way of casting dynamic object to a concrete class
        /// </summary>
        public static T Convert<T>(dynamic obj) where T : class
        {
            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
        }

        [Test]
        public void CastTest()
        {
            decimal a = 10;
            dynamic s1 = new DecimalStruct(a);

            var s2 = Convert<DecimalStruct>(s1);

            Assert.AreEqual(a, s1.A);
            Assert.AreEqual(a, s2.A);

            Assert.AreEqual(a.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), s1.A.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            Assert.AreEqual(a.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), s2.A.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // this fails because "10.0" is not equal "10"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following example to convert dynamic to concrete

```
    var typeName = "YourNamespace.ExampleObj";

    object obj = new
    {
        A = 5,
        B = "xx"
    };

    var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj);
    Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    ExampleObj instance = (ExampleObj)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    instance.A = (int)props["A"].GetValue(obj);
    instance.B = (string)props["B"].GetValue(obj);

//serialize the instance now...
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what the properties of the object will be though. As you can see I tried creating a generic method for that purpose. And the structures can be bigger than just one level. I think using reflections is the way to go with that but I don't think it will be that simple.